# JQuery autocomplete is not working, TypeError undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I got a problem concerning query autocomplete. I read so many posts about this issue, but all suggestions I tried are so far not working.

This is my website http://www.lactoscanner.com
and I can see that autocomplete is undefined.

> > TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery("#searchfield").autocomplete({
> >                             source:'handlesearch.php',
> >                             minLength:1

For me it seems that I just miss something. I actually don't load any extra js files which could mess up something. So I wonder why it's not working.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using multiple versions of jQuery -- 1.9.1 and 1.8.0 -- then change your code to:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
                $("#searchfield").autocomplete({
                    source:'handlesearch.php',
                    minLength:1
                });
            })
```

Comment: Don't you need to call jQuery.noConflict() before your code to get the second version of jquery to release the dollar sign variable back to the first instance of jquery?

Comment: It's not necessary.  As long as the code for each version follows that version and the $ variable is passed to the ready function it should work fine. As a matter of fact this technique allows one to use more than two versions on a single page.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I had to see it for myself. http://jsfiddle.net/en4yqumd/

Answer (score 1):

Like @PeterKA said, you're loading two instances of jquery. I'd eliminate one of the instances of jquery if you could. Then make sure all jquery plugins are still called after jquery is loaded. Right now you're attaching your plugins to one instance of jquery, but then loading a second instance.